# Create a method that returns an array of strings from a text file in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to read in from a text file in C. The method I am trying to create will return an array of strings having every line from the text file an index of the array. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong although I am sure it is something very simple.

```
// returns an array of strings from a text file; lines is the number of lines
char *file_array(int lines) 
{
    char text[50][150],buffer[150];

    int i=0;
    FILE *file_in;
    file_in=fopen("test.txt","r");

    if (file_in == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    }

    while (fgets(buffer,150,file_in)) {
        strcpy(text[i],buffer);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(file_in);
    return text;
}

int main()
{
    //totalLines is used to get the sizeof the array; this is the number of lines
    //in the text file
    int totalLines;
    totalLines = lines();   

    char *strings_from_file[totalLines];
    strings_from_file = file_array(totalLines);

    printf("index 2 of text file: %s",strings_from_file[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error when compiling

```
io.c:110:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[(sizetype)(totalLines)]’ from type ‘char *’ strings_from_file = file_array(totalLines);
                ^
    fabio93@fabio93:~/Documents/c_apps/io_test$ gcc -o str_arr_file io.c 
    io.c: In function ‘file_array’:
    io.c:86:2: warning: return from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
      return text;
      ^
    io.c:86:2: warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
    io.c: In function ‘main’:
    io.c:110:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char *[(sizetype)(totalLines)]’ from type ‘char *’ strings_from_file = file_array(totalLines);
```

I would consider myself a beginner in C, so please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: What is your question? You imply you are doing something wrong but you haven't told us about any errors or unexpected output.

Comment: I edited it so you can see the error that comes up

Comment: As it says, you can't return a local array. malloc the string from the heap and return that, or allocate the string in the caller and pass a pointer to it into the routine which fills it. (If you can't predict the maximum length of the returned string, prefer the former.)

Comment: Your common function is completely wrong.

Comment: I am not too sure how to use malloc. Would it be better to have that method a void method and have it modify a global array? Would I use malloc like this? strings_from_file = (char*)maaloc(150); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your function, you create variable on stack which gets lost when function returns. So `return text` is undefined behaviour.
Better way is to allocate space on heap using `malloc` and return that.

```
char **file_array(int lines) 
{
    char **text;
    text = malloc(sizeof(char*)*50);   //no of strings
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++)
        text[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*150);  ..no of chars in each string


    //do things with text..you can use in same way as your example

    return text;
}
```

In your main program, use double pointer

```
char ** strings_from_file;
strings_from_file = file_array(totalLines);
```

Comment: I am getting this message now:

io.c: In function ‘file_array’:
io.c:71:9: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ [enabled by default]
  text = malloc(sizeof(char*)*50); //number of strings
         ^
io.c:71:7: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  text = malloc(sizeof(char*)*50); //number of strings
       ^
io.c:88:7: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
   text[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*150); //number of chars in each string

Comment: add header `stdlib.h`

Comment: @self a victory for not casting malloc

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with double pointers through a function (passing a double pointer as parameter aka **triple pointer**!), here are some codes I wrote a very long time ago to address specifically that problem.

I hope it can be useful to those having trouble with double/triple pointers. Note that I'm working with integers, but the idea also applies to other types.

---

### Double pointer via function (triple pointer)

I think the important things to note are the following syntaxes

- how to declare `int ***coco_a`
- how to allocate1 `*coco_a = (int **) calloc(ROW, sizeof(int *));`
- how to allocate2 `(*coco_a)[i] = (int *) calloc(COL, sizeof(int));`
- how to populate `scanf("%d", &(*coco_a)[i][j]);`

**It took me a long time to realize that `&(*coco_a)` works and `&*coco_a` (or `coco_a`) does not work**!

Here's the test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 2

void aloca(int ***coco_a)
{   
    *coco_a = (int **) calloc(ROW, sizeof(int *));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<ROW; ++i) {
        (*coco_a)[i] = (int *) calloc(COL, sizeof(int));
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<COL; ++j) {
            scanf("%d", &(*coco_a)[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int **coco_m;
    aloca(&coco_m);

    int i, j;
    /*for(i=0; i<ROW; ++i)
        for(j=0; j<COL; ++j)
            scanf("%d", &coco_m[i][j]);*/

    for(i=0; i<ROW; ++i)
        for(j=0; j<COL; ++j)
            printf("coco[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, coco_m[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The following illustrates the usage of contiguous versus non-contiguous double pointers.

### Contiguous versus non-contiguous allocation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 3


int main(void)
{
    int i, j, val = 0;

    /* Allocation and assignment */
    int **doub_pointer = (int **) calloc(ROW, sizeof(int *));
    printf("\ndoub_pointer        = %d\n", doub_pointer);        

    for(i=0; i < ROW; ++i) {
            doub_pointer[i] = (int *) calloc(COL, sizeof(int));
            if(i == 0) printf("*doub_pointer       = %d\n", *doub_pointer);
            for(j=0; j < COL; ++j) {
                    doub_pointer[i][j] = val++;
                    printf("&doub_pointer[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, &doub_pointer[i][j]);
            }
    }

    /* Printing */
    for(i=0; i < ROW; ++i) {
            for(j=0; j < COL; ++j){
                    printf("doub_pointer[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, doub_pointer[i][j]);
            }
    }
    printf("sizeof(doub_pointer)    = %d\n", sizeof(doub_pointer)/sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(doub_pointer[0]) = %d\n", sizeof(doub_pointer[0])/sizeof(int));

    /* Freeing */
    for(i=0; i < ROW; ++i) free(doub_pointer[i]);
    free(doub_pointer);

    /*******************************************************************/

    val = 0;

    /* Allocation and assignment */
    int (*pointer)[COL] = (int (*)[COL]) calloc(ROW, sizeof(int [COL]));
    printf("\npointer        = %d\n", pointer);

    for(i=0; i < ROW; ++i) {
            for(j=0; j < COL; ++j){
                    pointer[i][j] = val++;
                    printf("&pointer[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, &pointer[i][j]);
            }
    }

    /* Printing */
    for(i=0; i < ROW; ++i) {
            for(j=0; j < COL; ++j){
                    printf("pointer[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, pointer[i][j]);
            }
    }
    printf("sizeof(pointer)    = %d\n", sizeof(pointer)/sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(pointer[0]) = %d\n", sizeof(pointer[0])/sizeof(int));

    /* Freeing */
    free(pointer);        

    /*******************************************************************/

    int true_2D[ROW][COL];
    printf("\nsizeof(true_2D)     = %d\n", sizeof(true_2D)/sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It took me a long time to realize that &(*coco_a) works and &*coco_a (or coco_a) does not work!" - this is badly worded, those are only different in the context where there is another operator immediately to the right that binds more tightly than `&`

Comment: You can make `aloca` easier to read by doing `int **ptr;`, allocating that, and then ending with `*coco_a = ptr;`. That avoids you having to write `(*coco_a)` everywhere, and also makes it easier to clean up if there is an allocation failure.

Comment: Also, using this calloc idiom is easier to read and less likely to get wrong: `pointer = calloc(ROW, sizeof *pointer);`

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks for your observations. Maybe I should not have posted any answer since I don't program C for more than 5 years. I just remembered having the same trouble as OP, and I remembered I had those codes (and I could find them still on my hard drive!)